# Copy IP Tables rules from one server to another

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, iptables

I have a server with iptables rules setup. I want to use the same rules on a new server. Can I somehow copy/paste them or download/re-upload them using terminal? I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: This question belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), not SO.

Comment: `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`

Comment: @JakeGould I disagree, but respect your opinion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. Save it as follows:

```
sudo iptables-save > iptables.conf
```

Restore it as follows:

```
sudo iptables-restore < iptables.conf
```

And since it’s all in a text file—in this case `iptables.conf`—you can then do further editing and tweaks based on machine specific parameters and scenarios.

Also, if you plan on retaining rules on reboot, consider having `iptables-persistent` installed and then copying the rules into the area that `iptables-persistent` loads them:

```
sudo cp iptables.conf /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Above is for IPv4 rules. For for IPV6 rules do this:

```
sudo cp iptables.conf /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo iptables-save > [filename]
```

to save them in a file, then use

```
sudo iptables-restore < [filename]
```

once you've copied the file over.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `iptables-save` utility to save rules to file and `iptables-restore` to restore them form file.

And then use `scp` to copy saved rules form one serve to another.